# firebase retrieve data in ionic 2 with typings

Tags: ionic-framework, angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, ionic2

Using now firebase 3 thanks to Jorge, I've a contact list page and all contacts are saved in, you guess.. Firebase.
The problem is when I try to get all contacts name I get this error :

> Argument of type '(childSnapshot: DataSnapshot) => void' is not
>   assignable to parameter of type '(_0: DataSnapshot) => boolean'. Type
>   'void' is not assignable to type 'boolean'.

My function is simple :

```
getContactsList(){
    var refContact = firebase.database().ref('contactslist/'+firebase.auth().currentUser.uid)
    refContact.on('value', (snapshot) => {
        var arr = []
        snapshot.forEach(function (childSnapshot) {
            var data = childSnapshot.val()
            data['id'] = childSnapshot.key
            arr.push(data);
        });
    }, (error) => {
        console.log("ERROR:", error)
    });
}
```

Did you experience the same issue ?

Comment: I have the same problem did you manage to solve it?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39845758/argument-of-type-snap-datasnapshot-void-is-not-assignable-to-parameter-o
for perfect answer :-)