# Argument of type '(snap: DataSnapshot) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type '(a: DataSnapshot) => boolean'

Tags: ionic-framework, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, ionic2

I've already read several questions and answers about this problem but wasn't able to solve it.

I'm using Ionic2 and I have a method which retrieves data from Firebase Database v3.
I don't understand why I get following error in console when I do `ionic serve`:

```
Error TS2345: Argument of type '(snap: DataSnapshot) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type '(a: DataSnapshot) => boolean'.
  Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'boolean'.
```

This is the method:

```
constructor(private http: Http) {

    firebase.database().ref('users').orderByChild("id").on("value", function(snapshot){
                    let items = [];
                    snapshot.forEach(snap => {
                        items.push({
                            uid: snap.val().uid,
                            username: snap.val().username,
                        });
                    });
                });
            }
}
```

Answer (score 35, accepted):

The `forEach` method in the `DataSnapshot` has this signature:

```
forEach(action: (a: firebase.database.DataSnapshot) => boolean): boolean;
```

as the `action` can return `true` to short-circuit the enumeration and return early. If a falsy value is returned, enumeration continues normally. (This is mentioned in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.DataSnapshot#forEach).)

To appease the TypeScript compiler, the simplest solution would be to return `false` (to continue enumerating the child snapshots):

```
database()
    .ref("users")
    .orderByChild("id")
    .on("value", (snapshot) => {
        let items = [];
        snapshot.forEach((snap) => {
            items.push({
                uid: snap.val().uid,
                username: snap.val().username
            });
            return false;
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

For Typescript version I came out with this solution:

```
db
  .ref(`jobs`)
  .orderByChild("counter")
  .on("value", (querySnapshot) => {
    const jobs: any[] = [];
    querySnapshot.forEach((jobRef) => {
      jobs.push(jobRef.val());
    });
    jobs.forEach(async (job) => {
      await minuteRT(job);
    });
    res.status(200).send("done!");
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had to `return true`, to cancel the enumeration:

```
// You can cancel the enumeration at any point by having your callback
// function return true. For example, the following code sample will only
// fire the callback function one time:

var query = firebase.database().ref("users").orderByKey();
query.once("value")
  .then(function(snapshot) {
    snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
      var key = childSnapshot.key; // "ada"

      // Cancel enumeration
      return true;
  });
});
```

Documentation:  [https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/v8/firebase.database.DataSnapshot#foreach][1]