# Firebase not receiving data before view loaded - empty array returned before filled

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, callback, firebase-realtime-database

In the following code I save each item's key and an email address in one table, and to retrieve the object to fetch from the original table using said key. I can see that the items are being put into the `rawList` array when I console.log, but the function is returning `this.cartList` before it has anything in it, so the view doesn't receive any of the data. How can I make it so that `this.cartList` waits for `rawList` to be full before it is returned?

```
 ionViewWillEnter() {
    var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
    this.cartData.getCart().on('value', snapshot => {
        let rawList = [];
        snapshot.forEach(snap => {
          if (user.email == snap.val().email) {
            var desiredItem = this.goodsData.findGoodById(snap.val().key);
            desiredItem.once("value")
            .then(function(snapshot2) {
              rawList.push(snapshot2);
            });
            return false
          }
        });
        console.log(rawList);
        this.cartList = rawList;
    });
  }
```

I have tried putting the this.cartList = rawList in a number of different locations (before `return false`, even inside the `.then` statement, but that did not solve the problem.

Comment: return statements only work for synchonous work. Firebase queries are async, so you need to return the array via callback.

Answer (score 1):

The following function call is asynchronous and you're falling out of scope before  `rawList` has a chance to update because this database call takes a reasonably long time:

```
desiredItem.once("value").then(function(snapshot2) {
    rawList.push(snapshot2);
});
```

You're also pushing the snapshot directly to this list, when you should be pushing `snapshot2.val()` to get the raw value.

Here's how I would fix your code:

```
ionViewWillEnter() {
    var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
    this.cartData.getCart().on('value', snapshot => {
        // clear the existing `this.cartList`
        this.cartList = [];
        snapshot.forEach(snap => {
          if (user.email == snap.val().email) { 
            var desiredItem = this.goodsData.findGoodById(snap.val().key);
            desiredItem.once("value")
            .then(function(snapshot2) {
              // push directly to the cartList
              this.cartList.push(snapshot2.val());
            });
          }
          return false;
        });
    });
  }
```

Comment: I'm getting an `Unsyntactic continue ... You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type`

Comment: I'm getting the same error message as: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39845758/argument-of-type-snap-datasnapshot-void-is-not-assignable-to-parameter-o, which is likely why the false was there

Comment: @maudulus Apologies, I was not aware of this. Try my updated answer.

Comment: `Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.cartList')` - some sort of scoping issue

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the Promise (async .once() call to firebase) inside the forEach loop (sync). The forEach Loop is not gonna wait for the then() statement so then on the next iteration the data of the previous iteration is just lost...

```js
let snapshots = [1, 2, 3];
let rawList = [];

snapshots.forEach((snap) => {
  console.log(rawList.length)
  fbCall = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(function() {
      resolve("Success!");
    }, 2500)
  });
  fbCall.then((result) => {
    rawList.push(result);
  });
})
```

You need forEach to push the whole Promise to the rawList and Then wait for them to resolve and do sth with the results.

```js
var snapshots = [1, 2, 3];
var rawList = [];
var counter = 0;

snapshots.forEach((snap) => {
  console.log(rawList.length)
  var fbCall = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(function() {
      resolve("Success!" + counter++);
    }, 1500)
  });
  rawList.push(fbCall);
})

Promise.all(rawList).then((res) => {
  console.log(res[0]);
  console.log(res[1]);
  console.log(res[2]);
});
```

The thing is, it is still a bit awkward to assign this.cartList = Promise.all(rawList) as it makes it a Promise. So you might want to rethink your design and make something like a getCartList Service? (dont know what ur app is like :p)

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using angular you should also be using `angularfire2`, which makes use of `Observables` which will solve this issue for you. You will still be using the normal SDK for many things but for fetching and binding data it is not recommended to use Firebase alone without `angularfire2` as it makes these things less manageable.

The nice things about this approach is that you can leverage any methods on `Observable` such as `filter`, `first`, `map` etc.

After installing it simply do:

```
public items$: FirebaseListObservable<any[]>;

this.items$ = this.af.database.list('path/to/data');
```

And in the view:

```
{{items$ | async}}
```

In order to wait for the data to appear.

Answer (score 0):

Use [AngularFire2](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2) and [RxJS](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/) this will save you a lot of time, and you will do it in the proper and maintainable way by using the RxJS operators, you can learn about those operators here [learnrxjs](https://www.learnrxjs.io/)