# Get a value with column name in Ionic 3 with FireBase

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-realtime-database

I used the following code block to fetch only a row of data;

```
db.database.ref('/User/').orderByChild('uID').equalTo(this.uID).once('value', (snapshot) => {
    console.log(snapshot.val());
})
```

Here is the output;

```
{-L88gtymS5pS3KWtZrmI: {…}}
-L88gtymS5pS3KWtZrmI:
email:"user5@gmail.com"
fullName:"User 5"
uID:"ksog0IbStTOFSJnVlED46vN32TB2"
username:"User 5"
__proto__:
Object
__proto__
:
Object
```

But if I wanted to get email value like this;

```
db.database.ref('/User/').orderByChild('uID').equalTo(this.uID).once('value', (snapshot) => {
    console.log(snapshot.val().email);
})
```

It says this value is undefined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
db.database.ref('/User/').orderByChild('uID').equalTo(this.uID).once('value', (snapshot) => {
snapshot.forEach(function(child) {
console.log(child.val().email);
   });
});
```

You need to loop inside the random id to be able to get the values there.

Comment: There is an error "[ts]
Argument of type '(child: DataSnapshot) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type '(a: DataSnapshot) => boolean'.
  Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'boolean'."

Comment: check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39845758/argument-of-type-snap-datasnapshot-void-is-not-assignable-to-parameter-o

Comment: Thanks, I added return false line to my code and works fine :)